# Поворот всего приложения qml Qt5.15

Tags: qt5, qml

Когда я задую размер загрузочной странице QML, то контейнер который содержит загрузочную страницу принимает тот же размер:

```
Loader{
    width: 700
    height: 1000
}
```

Когда я добавляю свойство `rotation: 90` то содержимое страницы переворачивается, однако контейнер остается на месте.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли сделать так что бы либо поворачивался сам внешний контейнер следом за страницей, либо его размер подстраивался автоматически под повернутую страницу QML?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать Layout или добавьте свойство для loader anchors.fill: parent

Answer (score 0):

Я делал просто: width=parent.heigth;height=parent.width